# Improving efficiency of adding a column to an array in a loop?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I wrote some code that goes to a book's ID based on a "dictionary" and takes the data from all the sheets in that book after the second sheet. That data is then aggregated into a single array. My question centers around the idea of improving the for loop in the if statement. That is adding the "supplier name" to the front of the subarray that represents a row in the sheet/data. I was told that this is inefficient as the code has to go through each subarray and add a value.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I did it this way because I am copying the values of a range which are stored as an array of arrays. So to add data, I have to reaccess the subarrays. Is it possible to add the new data (supplier name) at the same time that the values are being copied? would this be more efficient?  It was recommended to use an arrow function, however, I am not familiar with their usage.

```
function aggregate() {
   var combinedData = []
   var idArray = {
   "suppliername":"id",
   };
for (var supplierName in idArray){
   var sBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idArray[supplierName]);
   var sheets = sBook.getSheets();

   for (var index = 2; index <sheets.length; index++){
      var sheet = sheets[index];
      var dataLength = sheet.getRange("E5:E").getValues().filter(String).length;

      if(dataLength != 0){
         var dataRange = sheet.getRange(5,2,dataLength,14);
         var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
      
         for (row in dataValues) {
           dataValues[row].unshift(supplierName);
         };
         combinedData = combinedData.concat(dataValues);
      };
   };
};

var dataLength = combinedData.length;
const dSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheets()[0];
dSheet.getRange(2,1,dSheet.getMaxRows(),dSheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
var dRange = dSheet.getRange(2,1,dataLength,15);
dRange.setValues(combinedData);
};
```

Comment: How many supplier names do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for (row in dataValues) {
  dataValues[row].unshift(supplierName);
};
combinedData = combinedData.concat(dataValues);
```

#### To:

```
combinedData = combinedData.concat(dataValues.map(e => [supplierName].concat(e)));
```

or

```
combinedData = [...combinedData, ...dataValues.map(e => [supplierName, ...e])];
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I will add this in and see how it works. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Your code worked well. My question to you, if you wouldn't mind taking a moment, is how does this work?

Is it adding the supplierName as the data is being copied? Or adding that in memory after the data has been copied?

Comment: @RCBreeze Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new questions of of `Is it adding the supplierName as the data is being copied? Or adding that in memory after the data has been copied?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. But I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.